# Подпись к картинке не шире чем сама картинка. Как сделать?

Tags: css

Хочется красиво оформит картинки на сайте. Есть такой вариант:http://jsfiddle.net/GREF7/1/ 
Если задать ширину изображение в стиле точно, то все нормально. Если ширину убрать, то подпись растягивается на всю возможную длину.

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать, что б и размер картинки не задавать фиксировано, и ширина подписи не была бы больше размера картинки?

Comment: Большое спасибо всем ответившим!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для родительского блока нужно прописать:

```
.wrapper
{
    display: table;
    width: 1px;
}
```

Тогда ширина будет подстраиваться под наибольший инлайн-блок, то есть как раз под картинку.

Answer (score 1):

А [приблизительно так](http://jsfiddle.net/XgLWE/) подойдет?

Answer (score 0):

Может [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/GREF7/3/) подойдет? При изменении размеров окна браузера, изображение будет уменьшаться/увеличиваться пропорционально.

Comment: Все равно вы задаёте размер для контейнера. Мне кажется, что на чистом css нельзя решить поставленную задачу.

Comment: @Genson, в вопросе ТС я вижу что:

> "что б и размер картинки не задавать фиксировано, и ширина подписи не была бы больше размера картинки"

Про размер контейнера - не вижу

Comment: я понял задачу, видимо, по-другому. Размер картинки задан жётско лишь потому что она сама по себе большая. Вы можете заметить, что в исходном примере у автора в стилях дял картинки размер не задан, а задан только размер контейнера. И если этот размер у контейнера убрать надпись и растягивается.

Comment: Суть именно в том, чтобы не указывать размер картинки, а размер подписи растягивался не более чем ширина изображения.
Если задавать четкие размеры - уже не так интересно)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы наверно сделал как то так: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/GF8P2/
Если для вас такой вариант конечно приемлем.

Comment: Спасибо за вариант!
Хотя вопрос был именно про CSS, через JS сделать не так сложно.)

Comment: Так может не будем делать невероятный костыль на CSS и решим задачу с помощью JS?

Comment: @Genson, сорри за оффтоп, у вас на сайте meta property="og:image" криво задан :)

Comment: @dekameron, спасибо, недоглядел. А как вы заметили?

Comment: @Genson, дурная привычка "оценивать" код сайтов-визиток "фронтенд"ов :D

Answer (score -1):

Оберните картинку и подпись в div, width=auto(если не поможет, поиграйтесь с параметром display), либо сделать табличный аналог

Comment: Без задания размеров, бесполезно.

Comment: учи мат часть)))

Comment: Приведите мне хоть один рабочий пример без задания размеров для обёрток/ячеек/псевдо-элементов и тогда я с радостью возьму свои слова обратно.

Comment: <table><tr><td><img>подпись</td></tr></table>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GREF7/4/ и? Где тут одинаковые размеры картинки и подписи?